# Какие есть способы интернационализации WPF-приложения?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Пробовал создать несколько кнопок в отдельном окне,при нажатии на одну из них из `Dictionary<string,string[]>languagesDictionary=new Dictionary<string,string[]>();` по ключу ищется нужный массив строк и подставляется в textBlock`и и лейблы основного окна. Код получается очень сложным и нечитаемым.

Как можно интернационализировать приложение по другому?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914581/how-to-start-an-internationalized-wpf-project-in-sharpdevelop-4-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете папку Localization (это не фиксированное название, просто так удобно)

В ней создаете файл ресурсов (.resx) с названием, например, UI.resx.

Открываете его. Вверху переключаете видимость с internal на public.

Заполняете таблицу ключ-строка.

Это будет файл для "нейтрального языка".

Потом для каждого языка создаете файл UI.<код языка>.resx, будет как-то так.

```
Localizaion
    UI.resx
    UI.uk.resx
    UI.ru.resx
    UI.ar.resx
    UI.fr.resx
```

Затем в xamlе объявляете неймспейс

```
  xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:MyProject.Localization"
```

и в коде

```
  <TextBox Text="{x:Static loc:UI.<Ключ ресурса>}" />
```